# When voting on review audit posts and refreshing the page, the vote arrow remains lit, but the vote score is reset

Tags: bug, review, voting, review-audits

While reviewing [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/29529502) in the [Triage queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) on Stack Overflow, I often come upon a fake review, which I understand is intended to make sure that I'm paying attention and not just clicking the buttons as fast I can (which I don't do at all, to put your minds at rest :).

This time, I noticed that it was an audit because it was a post more readable than most in the queue, and it was asked 6 minutes ago, but it had comments from July 20th, which obviously makes no sense.

I tried upvoting the question (which was reported to have 0 votes in the audit) from the review page, and the vote count, as expected, went up to 1. Then, I opened [the actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68457787/16442705) in a new tab to see what it really was, and I noticed that the vote count there didn't change and my upvote on the audit didn't actually go through.

Then comes the bug. I tried refreshing the fake review page where I had upvoted, and the up arrow remained lit, but the vote count was zero!  When I clicked the up arrow again to remove my vote, the vote count (still, this is on the fake review page) went down to -1.

Also, when I remove my vote and reload the page, my attempted vote **was still there** (and the count is still 0).

It's inconsistent that the fake score changes from 1 to 0 despite the vote arrow remaining lit, and it also shouldn't be the case that the vote arrow should still remain lit after removing the (fake) upvote. Either the fake score should remain at 1 after a refresh, or the button should be deactivated if the score is to reset to 0.

Comment: What do you think the intended behavior is/should be?

Comment: 1) If it preserves that fact that I voted (and which arrow I used), it should also preserve the vote count. 2) When I un-vote and reload the page, it should save the fact that I un-voted too.

Comment: I see users filing bug reports that "there's something wrong with review voting" before they submit the review and seeing that it's an audit. +1

Comment: Yes, but here I understand that it's fake.  I'm just pointing out a _minor_ oversight.

Comment: Related? [In first post review, votes aren't validated](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380802/4642212)

Comment: Indeed; [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380802/in-first-post-review-votes-arent-validated#comment674394_380802) by @kemicofa states exactly the problem.